# VSCode opens already opened files in split tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

For a while (multiple vscode updates) I'm encountering this annoying behaviour. When I have couple of files opened in multiple panes (split) and I work on a file, a file opened in another pane opens in new tab in the pane I currently work on it's own. It's super annoying. Not sure I'm making it clear but let's say I have something like this:

### File A | FIle B

File C

I'm working on File A and without any interaction VSCode opens File C again:

### File A | FIle B | File C

File C

Tried googling but it's hard to figure out correct query for this :( I want this to stop!